$f(x) = \left\lfloor\frac{x- a}{b} \right\rfloor$ is continuous in Furstenberg's coset topology, so twin primes are counted by a continuous function.
Consider the function $f(x) = \left\lfloor\frac{ x - a}{b} \right\rfloor$ for fixed, $a, b\in \Bbb{Z}$, and $b \neq 0$.
Now consider the evenly-spaced integer topology (Also known as Furstenberg's prime infinitude topology), namely the topology generated by topological basis $B = \{ a \Bbb{Z} + b : a,b \in \Bbb{Z}, a \neq 0\}$.
Then I want to prove that $f$ is a continuous function in this topology.
I thought maybe $b(c\Bbb{Z} +d) + a \in f^{-1}(c \Bbb{Z} + d)$ is in the inverse image of a basis element, but there should be more as a floor is involved.
So I'm thinking switch the $a$ for $a' = a, a+1, \dots, b + a - 1$ and so $f^{-1}(c\Bbb{Z} + d) = \bigcup_{a' = a}^{b + a - 1} (bc\Bbb{Z} + bd + a')$.
Now clearly the $f(\text{ the union }) \subset c \Bbb{Z} + d$, but how do I prove that if $f(z) \in c\Bbb{Z} + d$ then $z \in$ the union?

Assuming $f$ is continuous.  Then $$F(n, x) = \sum_{d \mid p_n\#} (-1)^{\omega d}\sum_{r^2 =1 \pmod d} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{x-r}{d}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{r}{d} \right\rfloor\right)$$,
Is computed for each fixed $n$ as a sum of continuous functions.  For example $F(n, p_{n+1}^2 - 2) =$ the exact number of twin prime averages in the range $\{p_{n} + 2, \dots p_{n+1}^2 - 2\}$.
That's my second question.  Do I have this right?  Generally, for any topology in the codomain (that happens to be a ring), is the sum of two continuous functions also continuous?

Very nice question (+1)! I always get excited to see this topology being discussed. Do you happen to know of any sources (after Furstenberg's paper) which studies this topology? Also, what is the source of this question?

@SayanDutta I made it up, but no one AFAIK has applied these topological properties to twin primes.  Well that's kind of broad, but I've never seen discussion continuity of such functions.  Thanks for your support

Same here, I feel like there's more to this topology than one amazing proof! I tried to apply it to primes in arithmetic progression, but never got anywhere with that :(

@SayanDutta prove that $F(n, x_n)$ is not eventually vanishing, and you'll win a Fields medal.

@SayanDutta my advice is re-read some of your old posts related to arithmetic progressions, then understand an interesting approach again.  See if you can view it with new eyes

@SayanDutta let's discuss some ideas

Hi, thanks for the invite, but I really do not have many ideas. Some time back, I tried to see whether infinitude of primes in arithmetic progression can be proved using Furstenberg's method, and saw very clearly why it doesn't work (so clever of me to imagine I would notice something that Furstenberg didn't!). Following your suggestion, I checked out Golomb topology which was interesting. I do not have much to add to your post, except that it's a very interesting question. Let me think about it for a while.

@SayanDutta Thank you very much!  However, mathematics as a field is nothing more than the next generation of mathematicians noticing something that the previous generation did not! And also building upon their findings.  Although this is elementary formulation, it quickly delves deep into requiring something hardcore to solve it.   Anyway, it's been "a while".  Any ideas ?   Let me share with you my ideas so far.


The first idea is to search through the topological properties on Wikipedia and see if at a glance any of them can be employed.
Work modulo the kernel of a certain alternating summation transformation that takes the function $g(d,r,x) = \lfloor\frac{x - r}{d}\rfloor$ into the above counter function.  You can look at all the properties of floor and see what summations (under which the limit kernel is naturally closed being a module) apply.  So your argument goes, if twin primes are finite, then the counter is 0 eventually, meaning this other derived function vanishes also, contradiction.



Become really good at homology / cohomology, as then you can solve basically anything.


I guess the answer to my second question is yes if $+$ is a continuous function in the respective topology.  Which barely requires proof as all the open sets are cosets of ideals (everything is about addition).

@SayanDutta OMG, you're not going to believe the paper that google just dredged up for me now:
https://www.qeios.com/read/LA9ETX
They apply Golomb topology (therefore it can be extended to Furstenberg's usually easily) to prove Dirichlet's theorem on infinitude of primes in coprime arithmetic progressions, which is supposed to be a super deep result.  That is the paper I recommend us both read right now as soon as possible.   Take that as an answer to one question in your first comment.

@SayanDutta on that paper, there's a disclaimer.  Looks more like it hasn't been peer-reviewed.  But see commenters at the bottom.  I am going to try to see if it does work out, because if it does, these guys found a PFTB for Dirichlet's Theorem, and I think it should be noted by us number theorists if it is correct.

Hi, thanks for digging these up! The author of the paper you referred to seems to have no internet presence at all. There is an MSE user of the same name though. If there was a correct topological proof of Dirichlet's Theorem, I am hoping that would have made some noise in the NT community. I frankly have very little hope that it is correct.

About your other ideas, I guess the problem with me is that I simply do not know enough topology to go and attack these questions. I am not too aware of homology / cohomology either. So, if a question requires expert use of topological tools, I would probably not be able to help much.
Also, what did you mean by PFTB?

btw, your second question is probably easier to answer :- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Continuous_Functions_on_Topological_Ring_is_Continuous

Mathematicians used to call this topology "the profinite topology" before Furstenberg's paper appeared.

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh please go on! Where in PTFB did you find it btw? I have a copy of it - don't remember coming across anything on this topic other than Furstenberg's original proof!

@SayanDutta I don't think I meant to say this was in the book.  However I did mean to say I could apply it to twin primes.  Found errors though.  So I take it back.  Still working on it....   Essentially what I'm doing is trying to exhibit a family of open sets and some sections which exactly are either the twin prime average indicator function on the open sets, or $\pi_2$ the counter function.  It's very tricky though.  If we can do this, and the open sets cover $\Bbb{N}$.  Then by definition of sheaf, we have continuity of these functions (of their global sections).  Could be impossible!

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh How do you ping in chat? Your profile doesn't seem to have any email id :(

@SayanDutta I don't think we should chat any more about this particular phenomenon.  I finally realized the obvious: there's no way that the full function $\pi_2 : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ can be continuous!   So the only way this could possibly work is if assuming a finite number of twin primes makes the function some how continuous.   I am moving on to greener pastures, i.e. commutative algebra from Atiyah-McDonald, then eventually HomAlg and AlgGeom.   I did my best to bring this conjecture down from the realm of the mathematical gods, but alas have failed.  Perhaps AnNT + topology could work

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh That's what doing mathematics is all about - every day you find a new way to fail!

I assume for simplicity that $b > 0$, the same proof must hold for $b < 0$. For the continuity of $f$, start by strudying its fibres. For all fixed $y \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$
f(x) = y \Leftrightarrow \left\lfloor \frac{x - a}{b} \right\rfloor = y \Leftrightarrow y \leqslant \frac{x - a}{b} < y + 1 \Leftrightarrow by + a \leqslant x \leqslant by + a + b - 1.
$$
We deduce that $f^{-1}\{y\}$ is the integers interval $[\![by + a,by + a + b - 1]\!]$. You deduce you conjectured equality,
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(c\mathbb{Z} + d) & = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f^{-1}\{cn + d\}\\
& = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [\![b(cn + d) + a,b(cn + d) + a + b - 1]\!]\\
& = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\bigcup_{a' = a}^{a + b - 1} \{bcn + bd + a'\}\\
& = \bigcup_{a' = a}^{a + b - 1}\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{bcn + bd + a'\}\\
& = \bigcup_{a' = a}^{a + b - 1} (bc\mathbb{Z} + bd + a').
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f$ is continuous.
If you want to know wether or not continuity is stable by sum, the easiest way to do it is to use the standard fact that continuity is stable by composition and if you set $s : \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ to be the sum, you have that $f + g = s \circ (f,g)$ thus your question is to know wether or not the sum $s$ is continuous. It is true thanks to the equality,
$$
s^{-1}(c\mathbb{Z} + d) = \bigcup_{d' = 0}^{d - 1} (c\mathbb{Z} + d') \times (c\mathbb{Z} + d - d').
$$

I think constant functions are open in this topology as well, is that correct?

No, look at the definition of open functions, singletons would be open, which is not the case here.

Open $\neq$ continuous. Constant functions are always continuous but almost never open.

Interestingly the twin prime indicator function is also continuous, and the above function is a summation of those over an interval.

Also, if you take $a + b\Bbb{Z}$ where $b$ are square-free, then you get a coarser topology relative to Furstenberg and still retain a topological ring.   The above function is still continuous in that setting.  There are probably a few other topologies related to Furstenberg that you could take and still retain these mentioned properties.  It's because $\text{lcm}(b,c)$ is square-free whenever $b,c$ are, and cosets intersect together to form the empty set or a new coset with LCM modulus.
